# jMeter not handling complex SQL query

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter

I want to execute some complex queries using "JDBC Request" in jMeter to assert some "User Defined Variables" and is not working, it just displays the column names and not the values, is this a BUG or jMeter cannot handle this kind of complex SQL SELECT requests?

Here is an example of the SELECT query:

```
SELECT p.person_id AS card_number, p.acronym AS card_acronym, 
card.*
FROM stuff_vault stuff
JOIN vault_objects.stuff s ON s.id=prop.stuff_id_fk
WHERE s.card_id='12346452'
```

This is what is displayed - just columns with no values

http://www.imagebam.com/image/627cfd338192899

Comment: Sorry for silly question: does this query return any result when you run it from any other environment (e.g. from IDE)?

Comment: yes it returns, on oracle sql dev for example, but in jMeter it doesnt, and i wonder why...

Comment: my suggestion is that Jmeter is not as intelligent as Oracle Sql Dev, what i mean to say is that the syntax of statement should be made compatible as per Jmeter.